# WCF Contexts - how to reference soap data from client proxy calls

Tags: wcf

I am providing both soap endpoints and REST endpoints (json/xml).  I have methods decorated with the WebGet and WebInvoke attributes.  I know I can get the Web context via WebOperationContext.Current.

However for soap calls, would I use the regular ASP.NET `HttpContext`?  And then if so how would I maintain both situations?  Lets say I have a method that's decorated with `WebInvoke` for RESTful calls, does the `soap` calls map to this as well?

**example**

Lets say both of these methods lie in my "Car.svc"

Lets say I have this for my REST endpoint that's decorated with `WeInvoke`:

```
public Car Create()
...
```

and then I have this which I would assume if I made a clientproxy call to create and passed it an instance of car, would hit this method (soap):

```
public Car Create(Car carToCreate)
```

so lets say in this case, where I make the clientProxy vall via wsdl, Once it hits this method I assume I could get at the request body (the soap) via the `HttpContext` object as opposed to WebOperationContext for REST calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WCF service model makes available an [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for SOAP calls.  Hanging off of that is the RequestContext, InstanceContext and SecurityContext that you can access.  To get to the body of the message for SOAP calls, you would do something like this.

```
var msg = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
```

From there, you have access to the body through the GetBody methods.